# In Raft distributed consensus, what do I set votedFor to?

Tags: distributed-system, consensus, raft

I am trying to implement the Raft consensus algorithm. Here is my general understanding around all the times we set the `term` and `votedFor` attributes of a server's state:

1. Upon startup `term` is 0 and `votedFor` is `null`
2. Upon a server's election timeout, the server becomes a Candidate, increments its `term` by 1, and sets its `votedFor` to itself.
3. When a server receives a `RequestVote` RPC with a `term` higher than its own, it should update the `term` to the number observed, then update `votedFor` to the sender iff the receiving server has a `votedFor` of `null` and its log is not more up-to-date than the sender's log.
4. When a Candidate receives an `AppendEntries` RPC, and the sender's `term` is higher than or equal to its own, the Candidate should update its `term` to the sender's `term` then set its `votedFor` to the sender and have it's state become Follower, thereby acknowledging the sender as its legitimate leader.
5. In all other cases when a server receives any RPC request or response containing a `term` higher than its own, it should set its own `term` to the received server's `term` and set `votedFor` to `null`.

Together, do these make up the only 5 ways that `term` and `votedFor` are set in a correct implementation of Raft, and are these cases correctly summarized? I am confused about this because the paper only mentions that at certain times a node will go through a conversion to a follower which does not specify whether `votedFor` should be the value of the sender with the higher term or `null`. I am worried that case 4 is wrong and should be this instead: on `AppendEntries` if the sender's term is greater, then the receiver should update their `term` to that of the sender, then set `votedFor` to the sender, regardless of whether or not the receiver is a Follower, Candidate, or stale Leader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the "Rules for All Servers" of Figure 2 of the original paper:

> If RPC request or response contains term T > currentTerm:
>
> set currentTerm = T, convert to follower (§5.1)

in which case you are supposed to reset `votedFor` to `null`.

As a result, in your rule 3, when a server receives a RequestVote RPC with a term higher than its own, it should update the term to the number observed **and also reset the `votedFor` to `null`** (meaning that in this case, it will always vote for the requesting server).

Comment: What can lead to an endless loop where a request vote is resetting the election and not converging to a leader?